# I'm trying to mass replace some #'s in the middle of a line of text

Tags: yaml, notepad++, config

**Caveat**: *I'm not a coder*, but I'm trying to replace 1000+ numbers in a file (I will have to adapt this to fit several files to make the alterations I want, for example: in another file, I might have to change "Volume: 1000   #some comment") and don't want to do it by hand. I've been trying to figure this out for about 4 hours now, and can't make the connection to finish the problem. I'm pretty good at reverse engineering things, but I haven't been able to find an example that I can adapt to my needs.

**Editing being done in Notepad++**

I have gotten something to work but only if the # I'm trying to replace is at the END of the line.

**Example** of what I'm trying to Replace: (there are no Tab's, only spaces)

```
Mass: 500    #this is a commented-out description of this line
#Mass: 5000    #Using a "#" at the beginning of a line comments the entire line.
Mass: 50000    #Not all lines will have a comment
Mass: 900
Mass: 7860    #The Line above has no comment
Mass: 66    #The comments can change but are always at the end
Mass: 6909    #All comments are preceded by a "#" in the game config files.
```

**Expected Results** with working regex

```
Mass: 50    #this is a commented-out description of this line
#Mass: 500    #Not all lines will have a comment
Mass: 5000    #Like the one below this line
Mass: 90
Mass: 786    #The Line above has no comment
Mass: 6    #this is a commented-out description of this line
Mass: 690    #this is a commented-out description of this line
```

**NOTE:** All I'm trying to do is remove the LAST digit of any number preceded by the text "Mass: "

What I have tried that works, but only on lines like below:

(^[Mass: ]?=|[0-9]$)

**Input**

```
Mass: 500
Mass: 5000
Mass: 7860
Mass: 66
Mass: 6909
```

**Expected Result**

```
Mass: 50
Mass: 500
Mass: 786
Mass: 6
Mass: 690
```

As soon as I run into lines that have something AFTER the number, it fails completely.
Hopefully, I've given enough information, I already know I'm gonna feel really dumb that I couldn't find some simple 'key' that fixes the problem, but I'm getting frustrated now and figured I'd just ask for help.
Thanks

P.S. I've been using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test it, the files are game files with extensions: .yaml and .ecf

They are all text files.

**EDIT/ADDENDUM:**
Thank you so much, I was getting so frustrated before going to bed last night. That being said I made a mistake in my question. Your given answer was perfect for the question "as asked" but my mistake was that the *file data is indented* like so:

```
  Mass: 6909    #All comments are preceded by a "#" in the game config files.
  Volume: 500    #this is a commented-out description of this line
```

Would I be correct in assuming this would be the correct way to fix it?

```
^\h*#?Mass:\h*\d+\K\d(?=\h)
```

**Mistake/Addendum 2**

I'm literally going to copy out a snippet from the file, as it appears that not all the lines that don't have comments end with just the number I want to alter.

In case you're curious, I'm tweaking Impyrion Galactic Survival Files.

```
  Mass: 1386, type: float, display: true, formatter: Kilogram    # should be dynamic
  Volume: 99, type: float, display: true, formatter: Liter
```

That is a literal snippet from the file, again all I'm trying to do is trim 1 number off the end of the number directly after the target (in this case "Mass: ", and leave everything else along

Comment: You can also remove the carret `^` from the regex.

Comment: @Toto thanks, I do enjoy learning stuff, but always forget that sometimes you can remove stuff to fix a problem instead of constantly adding to it.

I did make a huge mistake in my question, I've edited it to show the mistake, any help appreciated.

Comment: See my updated answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `#?Mass:\h*\d+\K\d(?!\d)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
#?          # optional #
Mass:       # literally
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\d          # 1 digit
(?!\d)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Just tested it, and it works perfectly in the file (I didn't use replace all cause I wanted to watch what it was doing), but I changed about 30 entries one at a time and it did exactly what I wanted. I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer... I tried.

Thanks.